# Class pointer(uninitialized) printing to console

Tags: c++, class, pointers

This is probably a quick fix but I can't find a solution. I am unsure why, but the code output to this C++ program is just nothing, instead of printing "tag1" to the console. Am I using pointers incorrectly?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

class tag {
public:
    string tag_name;
    tag* child;
};

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    
    tag* tag1;
    tag1->tag_name = "tag1";
    cout<<tag1->tag_name;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using an uninitialized pointer, this is _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 1):

`tag* tag1` is a pointer to an object of type `tag`, it's not itself an object. Now, as it is not initialized to anything, this will cause `undefined behavior`. So to fix your problem you can write:

```
tag* tag1 = new tag();
```

This basically creates a new object of type `tag` and then makes `tag1` point to that object.

Now your code should work perfectly.

Also you should not use the following in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

..as it's considered as a bad practice. For more info on this, look up to [why is `using namespace std` considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the pointer named `tag1` has not been **initialized**. And you're dereferencing this uninitialized pointer when you wrote `tag1->tag_name = "tag1";` which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

For example, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9zgFseF5vp8GIa3v) the program crashes but [here](https://onlinegdb.com/EIAxIVGV1) it doesn't crash.

##### Solution

To **solve** this you you have make sure that this pointer points to some `tag` type object. For example,

```
class tag {
public:
    std::string tag_name;
    tag* child;
};

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    //create object of type tag 
    tag obj; 
    obj.tag_name = "original tag";
    std::cout<<obj.tag_name<<std::endl;
    
    //create pointer to object obj
    tag* tag1 = &obj;
    tag1->tag_name = "tag1";
    std::cout<<tag1->tag_name;
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/zTRxVd-KZ)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>